# ¿Cómo definir en Wordpress un formulario de contacto individual por cada post?

Tags: wordpress

Pensé en Wordpress para hacer un directorio para una asociación de comercios antes de usar un framework.

El objetivo es que cada asociado (comercio), tenga su propio micro sitio (post) dentro del sitio de la asociación y que se pueda establecer contacto directo con cada comercio.

Para lo cual, cada comercio tendrá su propio post y en cada post un formulario de contacto que debe llegar al correo del comercio. Es decir, un formulario por comercio.

Exploré la opción del Plugin **Contact Form 7** y veo que con este plugin podría hacer un formulario para cada post. Y cada vez que ingrese un nuevo socio, crear su propio formulario.

**Mis dudas**:
1.- ¿Existe algún método más "automatizado" para dar de alta a cada socio con todos sus datos y su cuenta de email sin tener que crear un formulario cada vez, como debería de hacerlo con Contact Form 7?

2.- Ya de paso, ¿hay alguna forma de que el formulario no esté visible en el mismo post, sino en un pop up o en un modal, o en otra página?

Agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: Tus preguntas son bastantes... y no se entienden bien. Sólo como idea: puedes tener la información de cada socio guardada en una base de datos y cuando el socio ingresa traes la información  y la presentas donde quieras o la usas con el formulario o lo que quieras, usando **una sola plantilla o formulario**. Esto del formulario no se entiende bien. En cuanto a un pop-up o modal, he de decir que, a pesar que ahora te aparecen en muchos sitios, por ejemplo para que te suscribas, los modales son una práctica que está cayendo en desuso, porque generan una *mala experiencia de usuario*.

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano por tus comentarios. Déjame ver si puedo explicarlo mejor, mi duda principal es que usualmente un sitio tiene un único formulario de contacto. En este caso, podrían contactarse con la asociación con ese formulario, pero para cada asociado, que tendrá su propio espacio dentro del sitio de la asociación, tengo que hacerle su propio formulario que le llegue al asociado, no a la asociación.

Comment: En tu comentario, sugieres que tenga una base de datos con los datos de cada asociado y luego llamarla en cada post? Esta base de datos sería independiente a la de wordpress?

Comment: necesitas un addon [dynamic text](https://sevenspark.com/goods/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension) para leer campos [meta del post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) es decir la página donde está incrustado el form, luego crear ese campo meta por cada página para que guarde el email asociado

Comment: para CF7 en popups google da este resultado https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-for-contact-form-7/

Comment: alo Malbarez, gracias por tus sugerencias. Voy a leer la documentación que me envías y comento por aquí mis dudas y resultados.

Comment: Carlos puedes usar la misma base de datos de Wordpress y crear en ella las tablas que necesites para gestionar la información de los usuarios. El formulario sería simplemente una especie de plantilla la cual vas a rellenar según los datos que traigas de la base de datos según el socio que sea. Es decir, no se trata de crear `N` formularios por la cantidad `N` de socios que haya, sino de llenar un mismo formulario (plantilla)  con los datos del socio X actual. De ese modo, trabajas al modo de Wordpress y no tienes que recurrir a plugins de terceros.